# Performance considerations for loading data from Object Storage into ADW

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

When loading from Object Storage into ADW using DBMS_CLOUD COPY, are there any parameters to be considered for performance improvement? I understand ADW manages its own and scales accordingly, but was wondering if this load is dependent on any other parameters at our disposal? Are there any performance benchmarks for loads from Object Storage into ADW? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are no knobs to tinker with, but there are multiple factors that impact your load performance:

- parallelism - the more resources you can user for loading, the faster
  you are
- file format - depending on the file format you can
  parallelize within a file - or not. For example, compressed files
  need to be worked on by one process. The number of files
  defines/limits the paralellism you can use.
- target table - if your
  target table is compressed then the insert will take longer than into
  an uncompressed table. (Consider loading data that needs to be
  available quick first uncompressed and then compress later .. or even
  better yet, access the file(s) in the object storage directly).
- geolocation - the closer the data is to the database, the less
  latency you hav. It also might have an impact on the overall
  throughput.